# Scala returning object type in if/else statements

Tags: java, scala

currently i have an abstract class called example, three case classes extending abstract class, and a function with a return type of example. in the function, when a certain condition is met, it is supposed to return an example type but for some reason it says: type mismatch, found: Unit, required: example

i don't understand why, as i am returning example type at the end of each if statement...

```
abstract class example
case class type1() extends example
case class type2() extends example
case class type3() extends example

def func(): example = {

if (condition)
return (val x= type1())

else if (condition)
return (val x= type2())

else if (condition)
return (val x= type3())
}
```

in the main function, i'm calling func()

Comment: Note: `return` is not used like this in Scala, and usually [not used at all](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html). `return` in Scala is not the same as in Java!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the parentheses after your returns is not example.

```
return (val x= type1())
```

doesn't even make sense: you are saying that x takes a particular value… and then to return this fact. So, if your remove the "val x =" (that are useless, anyway), you obtain :

```
return type1()
```

which means "return the value I just specified by creating a new object of type type1".

Plus, you should respect Scala naming conventions. In particular, classe names must be camel cased:

```
abstract class Example
case class Type1() extends Example
case class Type2() extends Example
case class Type3() extends Example
```

Plus, you evaluate the same condition several times, and there is no good reason to do so. Therefore, you should simplify how your function is defined. Also, you should not use explicit returns. Something like:

```
def func(): example = if (condition) Type1()
                      else Type2()
```

Also, note that, in your original code, type2 and type3 objects are never instanciated since *condition* is either always true, or always false.

Finally, your function has a side effect, since its behaviour relies on *condition*, which is not one of its parameters. You should not do that.

As a conclusion, your source code should probably looks like:

```
abstract class Example

case class Type1() extends Example
case class Type2() extends Example
case class Type3() extends Example

def func(condition: Boolean): Example = if(condition) Type1()
                                        else Type2()
```

Comment: I updated my answer in an attempt to elaborate as requested.

Comment: If the case classes have no values at all they should be case objects instead.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to implement else block after the last "else if".

Scala methods return the value of last expression in their body and conditional brach without else block has a type of Unit. Hence the error.